# How to scrape <li> tag with class like active/selected?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a list from a website. There are two different lists, and one will load only after the first option is chosen. Issue is, I'm unable to select the first option. I scraped the list of all available options. But after writing it, I have to select it from the given option, and I'm unable to do so.

I've tried using browser.find_element_by_css_selector(....).click(), but it's showing the `elementnotfound` exception even after putting the proper wait condition. I think that's because it's unable to find that element.

```
   browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#Brand_name").send_keys(company[i])
   element=  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#Brand_name_selectWrap")
   browser.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
   browser.find_element_by_css_selector("""#Brand_name_selectWrap > ul > li.selected""").click()
```

PS: Following is the link which I'm trying to scrape. I need all the mobiles listed company wide.
https://bangalore.quikr.com/Escrow/post-classifieds-ads/?postadcategoryid=227

Can someone kindly suggest some better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gather all options and their `rel` attributes into a dictionary and then loop that with appropriate wait conditions for the sublist to appear:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://bangalore.quikr.com/Escrow/post-classifieds-ads/?postadcategoryid=227')
options = {i.get_attribute('textContent'):i.get_attribute('rel') for i in d.find_elements_by_css_selector('#Brand_name_selectWrap .optionLists li:not(.optionHeading) a')}
input_element = d.find_element_by_id('Brand_name')

for k,v in options.items():
    input_element.click()  
    input_element.send_keys(k)
    selector = '[rel="' + v + '"]'

    WebDriverWait(d, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))).click()
    WebDriverWait(d, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#Model_selectWrap.showCustomSelect")))
```

---

I created a dictionary that had all the options for mobiles in it. The keys were the actual text that would go in the input box and the values are the `rel` attribute values for those elements. Each option has a `rel` attribute. It means that I can input the phone name via the key so as to generate the dropdowns to select your mobile from possible values, then use the `rel` attribute in a css attribute = value selector to ensure I click on the right one

The `rel` attribute inside anchor tags (<`a`>) describes the relation to the document where the link points to.

The `selector` variable just hold the current css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector for getting an mobile drop down option by its `rel` attribute value.

Comment: hey!! This is working like a charm! But I didn't understand it. What did you do with the selector and also option ? and what is real rel attributes? Can you please elaborate it little bit? @QHarr

Comment: I created a dictionary that had all the options for mobiles in it. The keys were the actual text that would go in the input box and the values are the _rel_ attribute values for those elements. Each option has a rel attribute. It means that I can input the phone name via the key so as to generate the dropdowns to select your mobile from possible values, then use the rel attribute in a css attribute = value selector to ensure I click on the right one.

Comment: The rel attribute inside anchor tags (<a>) describes the relation to the document where the link points to.

Comment: The selector variable just hold the current css attribute = value selector for getting an mobile drop down option by its rel attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

The element is covered by an other element so you'll need to use `ActionChains` to preform the click.

You'll needto import it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Then to click on the `input` only after that `send_keys`:

```
input_el = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#Brand_name')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(input_el).click().perform()
```

It's a good practice to use `WebDriverWait` to validate your conditions:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15)
input_el = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#Brand_name")))
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(input_el).click().perform()
```